# For paypal, can multiple purchases be added to cart - along with additional donation in user-selected amount?

Tags: paypal, cart

If I use a paypay button of "add to cart" is there a way I can have the user add their own amount to pay?

Alternatively is there a way to use a donate button and have it "add to cart"?

I'm adding paypal for a charity 503c.  We have various membership dues they need to select from.  Also they can add an additional donation of any amount they like.  Finally we have programs that cost a small amount that they can buy entrance to, for as many people as they like, so that too I'd like to add to cart.  ...so they can then check out all at once.

If you can point me to where this question has already been answered, or to code I can use or a paypal page that talks about it?  I've been searching for a while, and not finding the answers.  (I've added paypal to a merchant site years ago for setting a cart with mulitiple products bought.  That's the extent of my knowledge.)

I'm using paypal standard.

Thank you!

Comment: What language are you implementing your PayPal in? Plain HTML? Some sort of framework?

Comment: Plain html.  Thanks.  If there's something I can borrow from, I'm happy to explore things.

Comment: You could try using [PayPal's service shopping cart](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/shopping-cart) if it's HTML-only. I'm not specifically familiar with it. Alternatively, if you're going the free route, you might want to consider using an e-commerce framework, putting all the items in a cart, and then supporting a PayPal payment method. Evaluating these two approaches will probably provide you with some sort of solution that fits your needs.

Comment: I would second @Compass and recommend that you get setup with a shopping cart of some sort.  WordPress and WooCommerce are free and very popular.  I'd recommend going with that.

Comment: Thanks! -- I'll look at wordpress and woocommerce.  Our budget needs free since we try not to ask much $ of our members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a type field for amount into the input form for adding to cart.  It worked.

```
<form target="_blank" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<b>Amount $:&nbsp;&nbsp; (Example:&nbsp; nnn.nn)</b>      
<input type="text" name="amount">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="donation">
and so on till </form>
```